# How to include files from another project while publishing a solution with clickonce

Tags: .net, clickonce

While deploying a solution I found that clickonce doesn't upload some files from a project in a solution. I tried to find the files in the application files tab in "Publish" but it seems that it only includes the files from the client project and not other projects. How can i fix this issue? It should be something like an ability to add file dependancies to a project. The files are currently set as Copy if newer and Content.

Comment: Does your Client Project have a reference to the Project that isn't being included? If it does, then it should always include the referenced project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved by the following manner : added the files which were missing to the client application as Links to the actual files in a separate folder called `datafiles`. ClickOnce seems to interpret this folder in such a way that it adds copies of the items which are linked to the output.

Comment: Add as Link is an option when you Add->Existing Item
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Keep in mind to change the "Build Action" of the added file to "Content". After that you can select the the file in the "Publish" settings of the project.