# Why are content files from referenced project not published along

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce, publishing

I'm working with VS2019. In my solution, I have a C# project A, that needs a project B to run.
In B, I put a few files that I need at runtime in a folder "Data".
In A, I have the same kind of folder but I renamed it "Data_A" (I thought at some point that the same names might overwrite each other or something like that)

Running the project (project A as startup) in VS, everything works fine. When I check the bin/debug folder, both folders "Data" and "Data_A" are present.

The problem comes up when I publish project A. After installing the application, I see a "project_B.exe" file, the "Data_A" folder and some other related files, but not the "Data" folder.
Yet when I publish project B, the "Data" folder is correctly published.

Things I already checked:

- Project A has a reference to Project B
- the files are set as "Content" and "Copy Always"
- I tried changing them to "Resource" and "Embedded resource"
- Closed VS, deleted .vs folder, published without building before
- Changed Project B -> Properties -> Publish -> Application Files -> set the Publish Status of the missing files to "Include" (instead of "Include (Auto)" )
- Followed the top answer of this question : [File marked as Content -> Copy Always is not being copied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441513/file-marked-as-content-copy-always-is-not-being-copied). From what I could read in the output window, my files are definitely copied into the \bin, but they seem to be skipped when publishing to the publish folder.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: Try to add the files as link to ClickOnce. Here is a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32823541/8335151) you can refer to.

Comment: I'll try this solution out soon, for now I just cheated a bit and copied the folder in the other project. Although these files have nothing to do there, they end up in the published folder, so everything seems to work fine this way.